# HLSL 6.0 Vertex Shader returns wrong type without error

Tags: hlsl

Can anyone help me understand why the following HLSL doesn't produce a warning or error? I'm defining a type and returning it, but it doesn't match the function's return type. Is this allowed for any particular reason, or would this be a bug to report (to compiler team)?

I would assume it was a bug, but this seems like a pretty strange and obvious thing to go unnoticed. If not, is there a reason something like this would be allowed? The types are the same size, and possibly could be compatible, but I still wouldn't expect this to work.

The version of my dxc compiler is `1.7.2207`.

```
struct vinBake
{
    float4      Position        : ATTRIB0;      // local position of the vertex
    float4      Color           : ATTRIB1;      // color channels
    float3      TexCoord        : ATTRIB2;      // UV Texture Coordinates (z value represents texture index, if used)
    float4      Prop            : ATTRIB3;      // enhanced logic properties
    float4      Attr            : ATTRIB4;      // enhanced logic attributes
};
struct lerpBlit
{
    float4      ClipPos         : SV_POSITION;  // projected clip-space screen position of vertex
    float4      Diffuse         : COLOR0;       // diffuse color
    float3      Tex             : TEXCOORD0;    // tex coords (x,y) + texture array index (z)
};
struct lerpLine
{
    float4      ClipPos         : SV_POSITION;  // projected clip-space screen position of vertex
    float4      Diffuse         : COLOR0;       // diffuse color
    float       Factor          : TEXCOORD0;    // factor value of this position (0->1)
    float       Thickness       : TEXCOORD1;    // thickness of line
    float       Feather         : TEXCOORD2;    // falloff of line
};
lerpBlit main(vinBake vin)
{
    lerpLine pin;
    pin.ClipPos = float4(0,0,0,1);
    pin.Diffuse = float4(1,1,1,1);
    pin.Factor = 0;
    pin.Thickness = 0;
    pin.Feather = 0;
    return pin;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You observe implicit casting between structure types that is not a bug.

Two your structs `lerpBlit` and `lerpBlit` are structural identical, they have the same byte size and all underlying types can be implicitly casted if we flatten both structs. Floats `Factor`, `Thickness` and `Feather` are combined to `float3 Tex` that is just a composite type, array of 3 floats. `ClipPos` and `Diffuse` are mapped 1-to-1. It means they are eligible for implicit casting as in your case.

More than that, they can be casted explicitly if right-hand type has more size.

For example:

```
struct lerpBlit
{
    float4      ClipPos         : SV_POSITION;  // projected clip-space screen position of vertex
    float4      Diffuse         : COLOR0;       // diffuse color
    float3      Tex             : TEXCOORD0;    // tex coords (x,y) + texture array index (z)
};
struct lerpLine
{
    float4      ClipPos         : SV_POSITION;  // projected clip-space screen position of vertex
    float4      Diffuse         : COLOR0;       // diffuse color
    float       Factor          : TEXCOORD0;    // factor value of this position (0->1)
    float       Thickness       : TEXCOORD1;    // thickness of line
    float       Feather         : TEXCOORD2;    // falloff of line
    float       NewVar          : TEXCOORD3;   
};
lerpBlit main()
{
    lerpLine pin;
    pin.ClipPos = float4(0,0,0,1);
    pin.Diffuse = float4(1,1,1,1);
    pin.Factor = 0;
    pin.Thickness = 0;
    pin.Feather = 0;
    pin.Feather = 0;
    pin.NewVar = 42;
    
    // return pin; // Error! No implicit casting more.
    return (lerpBlit)pin; // That's fine, sizeof(lerpLine) >= sizeof(lerpBlit)
}
```

Additionally, you can output DXIL to check how your structs are converted and what output is.

```
dxbc2dxil.exe <file_with_dxc.exe_output> /disasm-dxbc
```

Part of the output for your case is below:

```
; Output signature:
;
; Name                 Index             InterpMode DynIdx
; -------------------- ----- ---------------------- ------
; SV_Position              0          noperspective       
; COLOR                    0                 linear       
; TEXCOORD                 0                 linear     

  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 0, i32 0, i8 0, float 0.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 0, i32 0, i8 1, float 0.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 0, i32 0, i8 2, float 0.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 0, i32 0, i8 3, float 1.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 1, i32 0, i8 0, float 1.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 1, i32 0, i8 1, float 1.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 1, i32 0, i8 2, float 1.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 1, i32 0, i8 3, float 1.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 2, i32 0, i8 0, float 0.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 2, i32 0, i8 1, float 0.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
  call void @dx.op.storeOutput.f32(i32 5, i32 2, i32 0, i8 2, float 0.000000e+00), !dbg !83 ; line:31 col:12  ; StoreOutput(outputSigId,rowIndex,colIndex,value)
```

With regards to reasons why it's so. I assume it's a part of support for composite types that allow you to write the code like that:

```
    struct {float x, y, z;} s;
    struct S {float r, g, b;} s2;
    struct {float r, g, b, a;} s3;
    s2 = s;
    s2 = (S)s3;
    
    float3 v;
    float4 v2;
    v = (float3)v2;
```

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that to be the case, but it makes the most sense now that you've explained it. For some reason, this implicit cast was throwing a runtime exception in D3D before I noticed it. Its possible the runtime exception was due to my pixel shader's use of the wrong data, though. Thanks for the information!